# Relationship between the angles, and alternative pythagorean theorem exponents.

Tags: geometry, regression-analysis

As everyone knows the pythagoran theorem can be used on triangles with 90 degrees angles using "2" as an exponent. Then on my geometry class I learned that for 3 numbers in order to be able to form a triangle they have to comply this " c < a+b "

I figured out that in an obtuse triangle pythagoras should work with different exponents between 1 or 2. I created a python program to realize which exponents to use in each case. For example for a 120 degree triangle the program showed that I had to use the exponent 1.26. Pythagoras Theorem works if I substitute the exponents by 1.26. "c^1.26 = a^1.26+b^1.26".
[Pythagoras with these exponents works in this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fft5P.png). I know about the law of cosines and the law of sines, but I think if there was only one way to use pythagoras with alternative exponents would be much neat.

I found the exponents that will fit to the pythagoran theorem in each case where I increase or decrease the angle between the values 179 to 61. Then I plotted a graph in excel relating the angle with the exponent that I had to use in each case, and I got this nice looking 
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eSxv.png)

I tried to make a trendline with help of excel, I tried polynomial, exponential, but none of those trendlines seemed to fit. At this point I have a table to know  which exponents to use in each case, but I think a formula obtained from the graph would be much helpful.

How can I obtain a formula from this graphs?

Comment: Your exponent also depends on the ratio between sides, not only on the angle. That makes your formula quite useless, I'm afraid.

Comment: My bad, in the example that I gave you I was using congruent sides, I also tried the formula with different lenghts of the legs and it was still working. It has the same properies of the pythagoran theorem, if you increase "a" or "b" you will still get the "c" value correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method doesn't work. Suppose the angle between sides $a$ and $b$ is $120°$, then the solution of $a^x+b^x=c^x$ is:

$x = 1.26186$, for $a=1$ and $b=1$;

$x = 1.25250$, for $a=1$ and $b=2$;

$x = 1.24001$, for $a=1$ and $b=3$;

$x = 1.25855$, for $a=2$ and $b=3$;

and so on: for different ratios $a/b$ you get different values of the exponent.

If $a=b$ then $c=2a\sin{\theta\over2}$ and equation $a^x+b^x=c^x$ becomes 
$2a^x=\big(2a\sin{\theta\over2}\big)^x$, which can be solved to give:
$$
x={\ln2\over\ln\big(2\sin{\theta\over2}\big)}.
$$
This is then the equation of your "nice looking" graph.

Comment: Yep, you were right, this method creates more problems than what it solves.